# How do I force a devDependency to use the dependency in AWS-CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use a certain library with a core dependency, however when I pass that type of object that he needs, its throwing an error as the sub library is using his own node modules as path.

Here is the object that I import and how I pass it:

```ts
import { Construct } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import { CfnDataSource } from "@aws-cdk/aws-quicksight";
...
constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
...
this.quickSightCdk = new CfnDataSource(scope, 'QuickSight', {
...
```

But it throws an error that it doesnt match since quickisight looks for the object in its own node module:

```
Argument of type 'import("C:/git/monorepo/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").Construct' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("C:/git/monorepo/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-quicksight/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").Construct'.
```

side by side:

```
'import("C:/git/monorepo/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").Construct'
'import("C:/git/monorepo/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-quicksight/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct-compat").Construct'
```

I tried passing "this" on the parameter but it doesnt work,

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'. Type 'MyStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'
```

I already tried updating both libraries to the latest but no luck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Any updates? Don't leave your questions hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not passing the scope and construct id to the `super` constructor, or not inheriting from `Stack`. Here's what it should look like:

```ts
class MyStack extends Stack {

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
  
    this.quickSightCdk = new CfnDataSource(this, 'QuickSight', {...});
}
```

Note that you should definitely pass `this` as the scope of your constructs if you want them to be created in your stack.

Comment: Not sure if you answered before my edit but I did try passing "this", and got `Type 'MyStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'`. Edit: Sorry missed the super part, but yes I am already passing scope to super()

Comment: Share more code. Are you inheriting from Stack? What are the versions of your CDK packages?